# Read S-Plus Database without S-Plus?

Tags: r, s-plus

I have an *old* (~1995) .Data database directory from S-Plus. Is there anyway that I can recover some of the objects contained in it without using S-Plus, maybe with R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to load it in File/Load workspace ...

If it doesn't work, try [package {foreign}](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#EpiInfo-Minitab-SAS-S_002dPLUS-SPSS-Stata-Systat) - functions `read.S` or `data.restore`.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I'd overlooked read.S. That worked perfectly.